# What (exactly) makes managed properties returning values in Display Template?

Tags: display-template, managed-property

My question is : What (exactly) makes managed properties returning values in Display Template ?

Examples :

I've a field which i can find in search but its mapped property is not searchable and its crawled property not included in full text, how this can be happen ? I would addn this field to Display Template and use the managed property that allow the fact that it is "searchable"

I've a field that i can't find in search but can be queryable with another managed property (not its managed propery) when using this managed propery in Display template it works !
- How can we query for a field using while we are not using its managed property
(I checked this : there are no relation!)

Any help would be appreciated